# Getting value from div which contains exact string using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to get a value from a nested div in a web page using Selenium IDE where class names are repeated but contain unique strings, such as the structure below, but am having no luck.

```
<div class='ClassName'>
    <div class="col_Num">1 </div>
    <div class="col_Val">5.00 </div>
</div>

<div class='ClassName'>
    <div class="col_Num">2 </div>
    <div class="col_Val">2.00 </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the value of 'Col_Val' from only the div that contains "col_Num = 1"? (the value 5.00 should be returned and saved to a variable)

Thanks,
J

Comment: Do you want to display 'col_Val' in both the div tags or only from first div tag????

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask tell us what you tried, and show exactly what your desired output is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it seems that you want to be able to store the column value based on the number you input. The best way to do this would be

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>css=div:contains("1")+[class=col_Val]</td>
    <td>value</td>
</tr>
```

Which will store the column value located immediately after the div containing the value you input (in this case 1)

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium IDE enter as: Command | Target | Value

```
storeText | //div[@class='col_Num' and contains(text(), '1')]/following-sibling::div | value
    echo | ${value}
```

Output is:

```
[info] Executing: |storeText | //div[@class='col_Num' and contains(text(), '1')]/following-sibling::div | value |  
[info] Executing: |echo | ${value} | |  
[info] echo: 5.00  
[info] Test case passed
```